# in Sql Server 2008 filegroup problem

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have table1 in filegroup1 and when i use "select * from table1" Query then 
error message out

**The query processor is unable to produce a plan for the table or view 'table1' because the table resides in a filegroup which is not online.**

What is the solutions

Answer (score 1):

There are some reasons why you get that error.
First of all the error occurs if you a have filegroup with a damaged or missing data file, so you might want to check this first.

You can check in sys.databases state_desc column. If this states RECOVERY_PENDING, you need to  set the file that is missing(or damaged) to offline state before you'll be able to get your database online and working.

```
ALTER DATABASE userDB MODIFY FILE (NAME=’damagedFile’, OFFLINE)
```

and then put the database online:

```
ALTER DATABASE userDB SET ONLINE
```

and it should work, but without you damaged file.
If you have a backup you can recover the damaged file from there.