# How to Restore data in File group databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups, database-restore, filegroup

I have a database with two file groups:

```
1- PrimaryFileGroup
2- ArchiveFileGroup
```

now I have a backup from first filegroup: **Primary.bak**. and restore with below script :

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET SINGLE_USER
    WITH

 ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
    FILEGROUP = 'PRIMARY'
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Primary.bak'
    WITH PARTIAL, REPLACE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE SaleTabriz
SET MULTI_USER
```

It successfully restores. but my another tables which are in **ArchiveFileGroup**, goes into with below error while I'd like to select from them :

> The query processor is unable to produce a plan for the table or view
>   'Customer' because the table resides in a filegroup which is not
>   online

**What is my mistake?**

Comment: You need to post a lot more details, ideally a script that reproduces this.

Comment: I don't have any script. all the scripts are refer to Backup and Restore filegroup Wizard.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2055021) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/56d24cc2-526a-4c60-8870-e2344cec8ef0), may be you will find something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont have enough reps yest to post as a comment hence the answer.

Have you tried bringing the secondary filegroups online:

```
alter database xxxDB modify file (name = 'xxxDB_File1', online)
```

Note: If the filegroup is in fact offline, i recall that if this doesn't work the only other way I know of to set a filegroup online is by restoring the file from backup.

Comment: When I Run this script this exception appears : ONLINE' is not a recognized CREATE/ALTER DATABASE option.

Comment: Apologies - I was working from memory but i just went back and checked where i got the info from when i did it and found the URL (http://www.sqlnotes.info/2013/05/09/bring-offline-file-online-modify-sql-server-metadata/ ). Please make sure you have a recovery plan in case something goes wrong as this is an "undocumented feature". Let me know how you go.

Answer (score -1):

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
   FROM DISK = 'C:\Primary.bak',
   FILEGROUP = 'PRIMARY',
   FROM DISK = 'C:\Secondary.bak',
   FILEGROUP = 'SECONDARY'
   WITH PARTIAL, REPLACE ;
GO
```

Comment: unfortunately Your Script is wrong (Exception : 'FILEGROUP' is not a recognized Device Type option.) Please test then answer.